# Is there a Bible-verse, what says that one must not quote the bible all the time?

Tags: prayer, religious-practice

Can someone advice me please. I have an acquaintance who is highly religious and reads and quotes bible verses and prays almost all the time, many hours in a row. Is there any bible verse, with what you could point to him, what says that you must not do it **all the time**, because it is clearly unhealthy and you will not be able to do anything else...

Comment: Sorry we don't do verse search questions here.

Comment: Ps 1:1-2: Blessed is the man that walketh not in the counsel of the ungodly, nor standeth in the way of sinners, nor sitteth in the seat of the scornful.But his delight is in the law of the LORD; and **in his law doth he meditate day and night**.

Comment: _And shall not God avenge his own elect, which cry day and night unto him, though he bear long with them?_ Luke 18:7.

Comment: _And it came to pass in those days, that he [Jesus] went out into a mountain to pray, and continued all night in prayer to God._ Luke 6:12.

Answer (score 3):

**Is there a Bible-verse, what says that one must not quote the bible all the time?**

There is no one verse that teaches we must or must not quote the Scriptures continually. But we should not drive others away from the Lord by being obnoxious about it either. Moderation is the key.

Scriptures indicates that moderation should be exercised in this domain. It is not rocket science to understand it.

> 6 Children, obey your parents in the Lord, for this is just.
>   2 Honour thy father and thy mother, which is the first commandment with a promise:
>   3 That it may be well with thee, and thou mayest be long lived upon earth.
>   4 And you, fathers, provoke not your children to anger; but bring them up in the discipline and correction of the Lord. - [Ephesians 6: 1-4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%206&version=DRA)

St. Paul desires us to teach what is sound doctrine. Simple bible quoting may or may not produce that effect.

> But as for you, teach what accords with sound doctrine. Older men are to be sober-minded, dignified, self-controlled, sound in faith, in love, and in steadfastness. Older women likewise are to be reverent in behavior, not slanderers or slaves to much wine. They are to teach what is good. - [Titus 2: 1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Titus%202%3A1-3&version=ESV)

St. Paul equally mentions the love (supernatural charity) is above speaking like angels.

> 1Though I speak with the tongues of men and of angels, and have not charity, I am become as sounding brass, or a tinkling cymbal. 2And though I have the gift of prophecy, and understand all mysteries, and all knowledge; and though I have all faith, so that I could remove mountains, and have not charity, I am nothing. 3And though I bestow all my goods to feed the poor, and though I give my body to be burned, and have not charity, it profiteth me nothing. - 
>   [1 Corinthians 13](https://biblehub.com/kjv/1_corinthians/13.htm)

Comment: is there a some verse, what says you must not pay attention to bibel all the time, because it is sick, and do some NORMAL life?

Comment: @user47520 what's abnormal about paying attention to the God who created you and everything else?

Answer (score 2):

The Bible counsels **moderation**.

> Do not be overrighteous,
>         neither be overwise—
>         why destroy yourself?
>   Do not be overwicked,
>         and do not be a fool—
>         why die before your time?
>   It is good to grasp the one
>         and not let go of the other.
>         Whoever fears God will avoid all extremes. (Ecclesiastes 7:16-18 NIV)

The Bible challenges us to respond in a manner that takes into account the **hearer**:

> Do not speak to fools,
>   for they will scorn your prudent words. (Proverbs 23:9 NIV)
>
> Do not answer a fool according to his folly, or you yourself will be just like him. (Proverbs 26:4 NIV)

The Bible also instructs us to **listen** before we speak:

> My dear brothers and sisters, take note of this: Everyone should be quick to listen, slow to speak and slow to become angry. (James 1:19 NIV)

However, we are also exhorted to **pray all the time**:

> Rejoice always, **pray continually**, give thanks in all
>   circumstances; for this is God’s will for you in Christ Jesus. (1 Thessalonians 5:16-18 NIV)

And to always be **prepared** to give the reason for the hope that we have:

> But in your hearts revere Christ as Lord. Always be prepared to give an answer to everyone who asks you to give the reason for the hope that you have. But do this with gentleness and respect. (1 Peter 3:15 NIV)

Jesus did warn people to not be showy about praying. That is pride, not spirituality.

> “And when you pray, do not be like the hypocrites, for they love to
>   pray standing in the synagogues and on the street corners to be seen
>   by others. Truly I tell you, they have received their reward in full.
>   But when you pray, go into your room, close the door and pray to
>   your Father, who is unseen. Then your Father, who sees what is done in
>   secret, will reward you. (Matthew 6:5-6 NIV)

Also, remember the example of Jesus. He is the Word, so technically, everything Jesus said while he was alive on earth would be "the Bible", so for at least one person, NOT reciting the Bible always would be an impossibility!

Answer (score 1):

Ecclesiastes 12:12. NLT

> But, my child, let me give you some further advice: Be careful, for writing books is endless, and much study wears you out.

Ecclesiastes 3:1-8

> There is a time for everything,
>       and a season for every activity under the heavens:
>   2 
>       a time to be born and a time to die,
>       a time to plant and a time to uproot,
>   3 
>       a time to kill and a time to heal,
>       a time to tear down and a time to build,
>   4 
>       a time to weep and a time to laugh,
>       a time to mourn and a time to dance,
>   5 
>       a time to scatter stones and a time to gather them,
>       a time to embrace and a time to refrain from embracing,
>   6 
>       a time to search and a time to give up,
>       a time to keep and a time to throw away,
>   7 
>       a time to tear and a time to mend,
>       **a time to be silent and a time to speak**,
>   8 
>       a time to love and a time to hate,
>       a time for war and a time for peace.

Answer (score 0):

The Bible gives a strict command about work:

> “And **that ye study to be quiet, and to do your own business, and to work with your own hands**, as we commanded you; That ye may walk honestly toward them that are without, and that ye may have lack of nothing.” (1 Thessalonians 4:11–12, KJV 1900)
>
> “For we hear that there are some which walk among you disorderly, working not at all, but are busybodies. Now them that are such we command and exhort by our Lord Jesus Christ, **that with quietness they work**, and eat their own bread.” (2 Thessalonians 3:11–12, KJV 1900)

Jesus used the word of God to overcome Satan while He was tempted.

> “But he answered and said, It is written, Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of God.” (Matthew 4:4, KJV 1900)

The Bible councils us to meditate on the law of God day and night.

> “Blessed is the man That walketh not in the counsel of the ungodly, Nor standeth in the way of sinners, Nor sitteth in the seat of the scornful. But his delight is in the law of the LORD; And in his law doth he meditate day and night.” (Psalm 1:1–2, KJV 1900)
>
> “Unless thy law had been my delights, I should then have perished in mine affliction.” (Psalm 119:92, KJV 1900)
>
> “It is good for me that I have been afflicted; That I might learn thy statutes.” (Psalm 119:71, KJV 1900)

Thus while it is important to study the word and to meditate on it day and night, we are also commanded to do our work and support those who are dependent on us. We are also commanded to help the poor and the destitute

Answer (score -1):

*Is there a Bible-verse, what says that one must not quote the bible all the time?*

**The answer is Yes.**

And the most powerful verse is written in the gospel of Matthew;

> " ***Do not give dogs what is holy; do not throw your pearls before swine. If you do, they may trample them under their feet, and then turn and tear you to pieces."*** (Matthew7:6)

The bible is the Holy Word of God to his children, and quoting the bible to a person without witnessing what is written there in their life can be seen as hypocrisy that Pharisees were known for during Jesus time.

St.Francis of Assisi words is a good reminder althought this quote is not clear if it really comes from him but it is a powerful reminder not to quote the bible without witnessing it in our life first.

> **"Preach the gospel and use words if necessary."**(St.Francis of Assisi?)

and Pope Francis compliment this very well saying;

> ***"Faith is propose not imposed."*** (Pope Francis)